# Remove “Permanently delete” permission from consent screen google

Tags: google-calendar-api

[image]

[image]

I select https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly for consent screen still it ask for edit,share and permanently delete permission. Is there any way to remove "permanently delete" permission ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### It seems that you are getting this consent screen because you are still using the old credentials.

Just because you had modified the scopes in the Cloud Console, it doesn't mean that these changes are reflected in your application automatically as well.

When **only** the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly`   scope is selected this is how the consent screen looks like:

[image: consent screen with appropriate scope]

#### *What you should do:*

Download the `credentials.json` file again (and if needed replace the old one) such that the change you made is reflected properly in the file and therefore in your application.

Comment: Thanks for answer. gives you upvote but I resolve it by this $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_EVENTS);